# Setting environment variables for a single package

Tags: buildroot

My current Buildroot configuration includes a package whose source is hosted on a GitLab server. Unfortunately this server has errors with its SSL certificate; when Buildroot reaches this package it tries to clone the repository, but Git throws an error regarding the SSL certificate and aborts.

This is reasonable behaviour, and the reasonable response would be to either:

- Fix the certificate
- Set up my machine to trust the certificate

Unfortunately, I'm also constrained by the following:

- I need an immediate workaround
- I don't have any administrator access to the server
- The workaround should work on machines without explicitly configuring them to trust this server

I think the `GIT_NO_SSL_VERIFY` environment variable is the simplest solution. If I add this to Buildroot's `EXTRA_ENV` variable, everything works as expected.

Unfortunately this disables SSL for *all* Git repositories cloned by Buildroot. Since there is only one Git repository with this issue, it feels wrong to disabled SSL for *all* Git repositories cloned through Buildroot.

It would be great if I could set `EXTRA_ENV` to add `GIT_NO_SSL_VERIFY`, but only for the package I'm having issues with. I can't find any suggestion that Buildroot supports this, but the documentation is sparse so I figured I'd ask here.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can define your package to download nothing (`<PKG>_SOURCE = `) and write your own download commands in `<PKG>_POST_DOWNLOAD_HOOKS`, where you can do anything you need, per-package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Buildroot supports this. For a given package, the `$(PKG)_DL_OPTS` variable is used to pass options to the package's download tool.

I realized that my package was not being cloned with`git`, but downloaded as a tarball with `wget`. Setting the package's `$(PKG)_DL_OPTS` variable to `--no-check-certificate` fixed everything.

Just as a note, the `$(PKG)_DL_OPTS` variable was only added in the 2016.11 release of Buildroot. You'll need a more convoluted workaround for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting `$(PKG)_DL_OPTS`, there are a few other hacks that can be used.

1. Add a rule that overrides `EXTRA_ENV`, but only for your package (but note that this will *not* work for legal-info):

   ```
   $(MYPKG_TARGET_SOURCE): EXTRA_ENV += GIT_NO_SSL_VERIFY=1
   ```

   Note that this has to come after the `$(eval $(generic-package))` call, so either at the end of the `.mk` file or in an external Makefile.
2. Instead of `EXTRA_ENV`, you can also override `DL_WRAPPER`:

   ```
   $(MYPKG_TARGET_SOURCE): DL_WRAPPER := GIT_NO_SSL_VERIFY=1 $(DL_WRAPPER)
   ```
3. Patch Buildroot to add an environment override to downloads. The simplest way to do that would be to define `DL_WRAPPER` differently:

   ```
   DL_WRAPPER = $($(PKG)_DL_ENV) support/download/dl-wrapper
   ```

   (But if you want to send such a patch upstream, it should be done in each individual download method instead.)

Note: I haven't actually tried any of the above.

Comment: Thanks! This addresses my initial question better than my workaround. Do you know if this stuff is documented anywhere? I don't see this syntax (colons used for scoping?) in the Buildroot manual but maybe I'm blind.

Comment: I actually can't get these to work. To make sure, I tried using #2 and replaced `$(DL_WRAPPER)` with some garbage string but it still uses the standard `git` behaviour, so I'm assuming my change isn't doing anything. Would #1 and #2 go at the top of the `.mk` file? So if line one is `FOO_UTILS_SITE=...`, would line two be `$(FOO_TARGET_SOURCE):...`? Or `FOO_TARGET_SOURCE:...`? Neither seems to work for me

Comment: For #1 and #2 it has to be done after the evaluation of $(generic-package), so at the end of the .mk file. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: The syntax of #1 and #2 is not documented in the Buildroot manual because it is not Buildroot-specific. In fact, it isn't used anywhere in Buildroot. It's GNU make. See "Target-specific Variable Values" in the GNU make documentation.